# Measuring certain times in the game in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to measure a certain time in the game? For example, i want to measure the time after the player pressed play button and until he lost/won the game. I know i should use os.time() but how to measure the time in the middle of the game?So would it be like this:

```
local startTime=os.time()
local gameStart = os.time()-startTime
local gameEnd = os.time()-gameStart
```

the gameStart is the time when the player presses the start button.
the gameEnd is the time when the player is playing the game till he lost or won.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's totally correct.

Whenever you want to measure a time interval just subtract the `startTime` from the current time. However, be sure to use the [`system.getTimer()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getTimer.html) function as it has millisecond precision:

```
 local startTime = system.getTimer()

-- some time later ...

local interval = system.getTimer() - startTime
```

---

On a side note, according to the [Lua 5.1 Reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) there's a good reason to avoid subtracting dates:

> The **returned value is a number, whose meaning depends on your system**. In POSIX, Windows, and some other systems, this number counts the number of seconds since some given start time (the "epoch"). **In other systems, the meaning is not specified**, and the number returned by `time` can be used only as an argument to `date` and [`difftime`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.difftime).